# How to install and use PyPy for my Python script?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, anaconda, pypy

Let me start by clarifying that I am relatively new to coding and a noob when it comes to everything that goes beyond python coding. For a project of mine which involves simulation, I really need to decrease the running time. After some research I got the impression that using PyPy interpreter would be a possible solution for my problem.

I use Spyder & Anaconda and I have been trying some stuff to implement PyPy, but I have found that my understanding is not sufficient and it has been rather time consuming without success. I have also installed VScode, for which I did succeed in loading and using the PyPy interpreter. However, I need to use several packages that I use in my original Python script; pandas, numpy and scipy. If it is even possible to use these packages, I have no clue how to install these for PyPy.

I have read on this website that it is recommended to use conda forge (right?) for these situations, but my Anaconda is often buggy for some reason. It would be amazing if someone can give a step-by-step guide or some advise on how to tackle this problem, either in VScode or Spyder&Anaconda.

I have downloaded PyPy 7.3.9.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The recommended way to get binary packages like NumPy and Pandas is to use the conda-forge packages via the conda. There is a [blog post](https://www.pypy.org/posts/2022/11/pypy-and-conda-forge.html) about it, the short version is

```
# create an environment
conda create -c conda-forge -n my-pypy-env pypy python=3.8
# activate it
conda activate my-pypy-env
#install some things
conda install numpy pandas
# run your script
python my_script.py
```

With that, PyPy will be no faster than CPython when running scripts that make heavy use of NumPy and Pandas data structures since they are written in C. In fact, the hoops PyPy must jump through to use these data structures in Python means that PyPy could be significantly slower. We have a plan for that called [HPy](https://hpyproject.org/), but it will take a while to happen.